# Refresh wp post on user1 dekstop when user2 updates it

Tags: php, ajax, node.js, wordpress, refresh

User1 is reading a wp post while User2 updates it.
Post is refreshed automatically on User2 desktop (use of `wp_update` and `get_redirect`  ).
I use to refresh post every x seconds to make User1 able to see updates without a click.

I'd like to make the refresh automatically on User1 desktop when User2 updates it.

Comment: Means the browser would need to ping the server and check for changes. So either Ajax calls or web socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's a pretty complex question since WordPress runs on PHP and PHP is a server-side language. But I think you can achieve that by using WordPress REST Api with a javascript framework like AngularJS or React. Here are two articles that you can refer to about these two options:

**AngularJS**

https://1fix.io/blog/2014/11/05/angularjs-json-api-wp-theme/

**React**

https://lamosty.com/2015/09/react-single-page-wordpress-rest-api-theme-tutorial/

*Disclaimer: I've never tested these stacks so I can not guarantee that it will work exactly like you want. I'm posting this answer so you can have a hint on what to look for.*

And also checkout this project that is a Node.js/Javascript based WordPress. It also uses React:

http://wordexpress.io/

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you. I will take a look and let your know.

Comment: I am on the way to do it